# Facebook api can't see my scheduled photo post

Tags: facebook-graph-api

My code get a list of image from directory and schedule it for publishing on my page.
Scheduling works: when i'm logged in as page admin, i can see scheduled post. But i can't see them loggin in with another account (which isn't admin)...What's wrong?

I've tried to use both 
$photo_details['published'] = "0";
and 
$photo_details['published'] = FALSE;
and
$photo_details['published'] = TRUE;

But nothing changed...

Thanks!

```
$page_info = $facebook->api("/$pageId?fields=access_token");
        echo "<br>TOKEN=".$page_info['access_token'];
        $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);

        //Create an album
        $album_details = array(
            'message'=> 'Album desc',
            'name'=> 'Album name',
            'access_token' => $page_info['access_token']
        );
        $create_album = $facebook->api('/me/albums', 'post', $album_details);

        //Get album ID of the album you've just created
        $album_uid = $create_album['id'];

        //Upload a photo to album of ID...
        $photo_details = array(
            'message'=> 'SEGUICI SU CASE DA SOGNO https://www.facebook.com/pages/Case-da-sogno/575064225848397?ref=hl',
            'access_token' => $page_info['access_token']
        );
        //TROVO L'IMMAGINE DA CARICARE
        //Imposto la directory da leggere
        $directory = "prova/";
        $results = array();
        // Apriamo una directory e leggiamone il contenuto.
        if (is_dir($directory)) 
        {
            //Apro l'oggetto directory
            if ($directory_handle = opendir($directory)) 
            {
                //Scorro l'oggetto fino a quando non è termnato cioè false
                while (($file = readdir($directory_handle)) !== false) 
                {
                    //Se l'elemento trovato è diverso da una directory 
                    //o dagli elementi . e .. lo visualizzo a schermo
                    if((!is_dir($file))&($file!=".")&($file!=".."))
                    {
                        //echo $file . "<br/>";
                        array_push($results, $file);
                    }
                }
            //Chiudo la lettura della directory.
            closedir($directory_handle);
            }
        }
        $cont= 0;
        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');
        while($cont<count($results))
        {
            $ora = ($cont+1)*12;
            $file = $directory.$results[$cont];
            $photo_details['image'] = '@' . realpath($file);

            $tempo_pubblicazione = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime ("+$ora minutes"));
            $pubblica_ora_data = strtotime($tempo_pubblicazione);
            echo "<br>ORA=".$pubblica_ora_data;
            $photo_details['scheduled_publish_time'] = "$pubblica_ora_data";
            $photo_details['published'] = "0";
            $upload_photo = $facebook->api('/'.$album_uid.'/photos', 'post', $photo_details);

            $file = $directory.$results[0];

            unlink($file);
            echo "<br>".$results[$cont];
            $cont++;
        }
```

Comment: Ok. My mistake: in application settings i changed from private to public and now it works.hope can be helpful for someone :-)

Comment: Would you like to change the comments in your code to English?